# How to not select fields in Many to One relations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In a Symfony 4 project I have an entity named `rendezvous` linked by a ManytoOne relation to other entities. One of these entities is `user` and I don't want to send the user's data with the result. How can I select all the fields excepted the `user` field with the doctrine query builder ? Is it better to put the relation in the `user` entity and not in the `rendezvous` entity.

Here are is my entity :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\RendezvousRepository")
 * @ORM\Table("rendezvous")
 */
class Rendezvous
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Immeuble")
     */
    private $immeuble;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $creation_date;
}
```

And here is my query builder that return all the `rendezvous` :

```php
public function findAllByUser($user){
      $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('rdv');

      $qb
        ->where('rdv.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
      ;
      return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Edit : I got the result I wanted to with the following DQL query :

```php
public function findAllByUser($user){
  $query = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT rdv.id, i, rdv.creation_date FROM App:Rendezvous rdv JOIN App:Immeuble i WITH rdv.immeuble=i JOIN App:User u WITH u=:user');
  $query->setParameter('user', $user);
  return $query->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `select` statement to specify what you want:

```
public function findAllByUser($user) {
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('rdv');

  $qb
    ->select('rdv.id')
    ->addSelect('rdv.immeuble')
    ->addSelect('rdv.creation_date')
    ->where('rdv.user = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $user)
  ;
  return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Basically the `select` statement will overwrite any previously selected items so you can pull exactly the fields you want (as opposed to addSelect which does not override previous calls to select). [Documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html).

If you want only specific information about `user`, you can do this:

```
public function findAllByUser($user) {
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('rdv');

  $qb
    ->select('rdv.id')
    ->addSelect('rdv.immeuble')
    ->addSelect('rdv.creation_date')
    ->join('rdv.user', 'u')
    ->addSelect('u.username')
    ->where('rdv.user = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $user)
  ;
  return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do I select fields from the user entity ?

Comment: ??? This is exactly what you asked to NOT include? If you want to include it then just use the query you wrote.

Comment: Not really. For example, if I want to select only the username from user and not all the fields.

Comment: Since you are passing `user` to your query, you already have the info without hitting the db for it. If you really want it in your query result, you can use what I have in my updated answer.

Comment: But the first code returns an error : [Semantical Error] line 0, col 19 near 'immeuble, rdv.creation_date': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Comment: And the second too : [Semantical Error] line 0, col 19 near 'immeuble, rdv.creation_date,': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Comment: I updated my question to show how I managed to make it works. But I'm wondering if I can do this with the query builder.

Comment: Is this `findAllByUser()` function sitting in your rendezvous repository? My answer assumes that it is.

Comment: Yes it is in my rendezvous repository.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need `$this->_em` to be used in a repository. Are you sure your repository is properly set up? Does your repository class extend `ServiceEntityRepository` (assuming your are using symfony 4) with a `__construct` method that sets the entity?

Comment: Yes my repository does extends ServiceEntityRepository. It was generated with `php bin/console make:entity`